# Angular 2/4 two way data binding does not work in observable

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

`Hi`, I use a third party library simple-peer which I did declared `declare var SimplePeer: any;`  in angular 4 , than the all logic of that is warped in `navigator.n.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` (asking user for video/audio permission) which is asynchronous function and the problem is that SimplePeer returns some data that I need to use in my html but I can't output the data in my html only with `console.log()` , here is the code app.component.html:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="targetpeer">
<button (click)="connect()">Connect</button>
<button (click)="message()">Send Message</button>



<p>{{texttoken}}</p>





<video #myVideo></video>
```

ignore the video thing, everything works except that the `{{texttoken}}` is not updated, it displays the same initial dummy data that I set in my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('myVideo') myVideo:any; 

  texttoken :any = 'initial dummy value'; 
  targetpeer: any;
  peer: any;
  n = <any>navigator;

  ngOnInit() {


    let video = this.myVideo.nativeElement;
    let peerx: any;
    let onJSTokenChange = new Subject(); // create new observable to obsere any changes to assign a value to texttoken
    onJSTokenChange.subscribe((value)=>{

        this.texttoken = value;
        console.log(this.texttoken);

    });


    this.n.getUserMedia = (this.n.getUserMedia || this.n.webkitGetUserMedia || this.n.mozGetUserMedia || this.n.msGetUserMedia);
    this.n.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:true}).then( function(stream) {
    peerx = new SimplePeer ({
      initiator: location.hash === '#init',
      trickle: false,
      stream:stream
    })

    peerx.on('signal', function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      // here I pass that data to the observable  
      onJSTokenChange.next(JSON.stringify(data));
      this.targetpeer = data;
    })

    peerx.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('Recieved message:' + data);
    })

    peerx.on('stream', function(stream) {
      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.play();
    })

    }, function(err){
    console.log('Failed to get stream', err);
    });










  }

  connect() {
    this.peer.signal(JSON.parse(this.targetpeer));
  }

  message() {
    this.peer.send('Hello world');
  }





}
```

here you can see that I assigned the dummy data to my `texttoken` , than I create an observable `onJSTokenChange`  to track if something changes to assign a value to `texttoken` , this observable gets data from `peerx.on('signal'` code when ever it executes and then the `onJSTokenChange.subscribe` gets that data and `console.log()` the data which works as expected however the `the.texttoken` receives the value as well but it does not do the two-way binding and does not update `<p>{{texttoken}}</p>` even though I `console.log()` it and it returns the correct value , please help been trying to figure it out the whole day :(

Comment: Maybe change detection is not run? Try and import `ChangeDetectorRef`, inject it in constructor, and then run `detectChanges()` https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: @AJT_82 agreed. It is possible your signal event is running outside of angular's zone, therefore causing the change detection to not run

Comment: Thank You @AJT_82  and LLai   , that was exactly the issue!!

Comment: @MikailMika You are welcome, glad to hear it worked! :)

Answer (score 2):

I just imported `ChangeDetectorRef` from angular/core and injected

```
constructor(private detector:ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

used it in my

```
onJSTokenChange.subscribe((value)=>{

        this.texttoken = value;
         this.detector.detectChanges();

    });
```

and it worked, thanks to @AJT_82 and @LLai